# Is there any Fluent Component (WebComponent/Blazor) that renders into a span?

Tags: blazor, fluent-ui

For example, I want a piece of **inline** text to render as a different color, how do I do that? The following code renders `<FluentLabel>` as `p`. I want something that acts like a `span` if possible:

```html
<p>
    Publishing:

    @if (cat.PublishedTime is null)
    {
        <FluentLabel Color="Color.Warning">Unpublished</FluentLabel>
    }
    else
    {
        <FluentLabel>@(cat.PublishedTime)</FluentLabel>
    }
</p>
```

Comment: You could always write your own `FluentSpan`  (or `FluentText`). So what exactly is your use-case?

Comment: @HH I see, probably the best solution for now. It's as the above code, I want a piece of text to have a different color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The maintainer suggests](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui-blazor/discussions/687#discussioncomment-6911526) using `Style` and set it to `display: inline`:

```html
<p>
    Publishing:

    @if (cat.PublishedTime is null)
    {
        <FluentLabel Color="Color.Warning" Style="display: inline;">Unpublished</FluentLabel>
    }
    else
    {
        <FluentLabel Style="display: inline;">@(cat.PublishedTime)</FluentLabel>
    }
</p>
```